# If a class has a member with copy-ctor but not mov-ctor cause the containing class defined with deleted move-ctor too?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I didn't understand this in C++ primer 5 ed. :

> For example, assuming Y is a class that defines its own copy constructor but does not also define its own move constructor:
>
> `// assume Y is a class that defines its own copy constructor but not a move constructor`
>
> `struct hasY {
>   hasY() = default;
>   hasY(hasY&&) = default;
>   Y mem; // hasY will have a deleted move constructor
>   };
>   hasY hy, hy2 = std::move(hy); // error: move constructor is deleted`
>
> The compiler can copy objects of type Y but cannot move them. Class hasY explicitly
>   requested a move constructor, which the compiler is unable to generate. Hence, hasY
>   will get a deleted move constructor. Had hasY omitted the declaration of its move
>   constructor, then the compiler would not synthesize the hasY move constructor at all.
>   The move operations are not synthesized if they would otherwise be defined as
>   deleted.

So I've defined `Y` as he said:

```
struct Y
{
    Y() = default;
    Y(const Y&){std::cout << "Y's Copy-ctor\n";
    Y& operator=(const Y&){std::cout << "Y's copy-assignment operator\n"; return *this;}

};

struct hasY {
    hasY() = default;
    hasY(hasY&&) noexcept = default;
    Y mem; // hasY will have a deleted move constructor
};
```

In main:

```
 hasY hy, hy2 = std::move(hy); // error: move constructor is deleted
```

- But the program works fine and doesn't complain about a deleted move constructor as he said?!

The output:

```
Y's copy ctor
```

- As you can see the program runs fine with me although I've tested it on many compilers with different versions and with different compiling flags. I guess it is a mistake in the book.
- I think class `hasY` is moveable and its move constructor is not deleted because that move-ctor calls move ctor of class Y which is implicitly not defined (not deleted but not defined) so it falls to use Y's copy-ctor So I think class Y is moveable through its copy constructor. Thus the program pints Y's copy-ctor.

** In cppreference it is said:

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted move constructor for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following is true:
>
> T has non-static data members that cannot be moved (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
>   T has direct or virtual base class that cannot be moved (has deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous move constructors);
>   T has direct or virtual base class with a deleted or inaccessible destructor;
>
> T is a union-like class and has a variant member with non-trivial move constructor;
>
> T has a non-static data member or a direct or virtual base without a move constructor that is not trivially copyable.
>
> The deleted implicitly-declared move constructor is ignored by overload resolution (otherwise it would prevent copy-initialization from rvalue).

- I also have an ambiguity between: "implicitly defined as deleted operation" and "not defined at all"? To me defined as deleted is as if writing:

  ```
  Y(Y&&) = delete; // generated by the compiler
  ```

And not defined at all is the same meaning of the expression.

*** To confirm my saying that class `hasY`'s move constructor is not deleted then here is just a simple:

```
struct hasY {
    hasY() = default;
    hasY(hasY&&) noexcept = default;
    Y mem; // hasY will have a deleted move constructor
    std::unique_ptr<int> upi; // This really causes hasY non-copy-able
};
```

- As you can see I've added a non-copy-able object of type uniqe_ptr to prevent the copy of hasY and the program runs as before with no erorrs which means hasY's move constructor is not deleted.

Comment: `hasY` does not have a move constructor, but it **does** have a copy constructor, so the compiler makes a copy of the object rather than moving it.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, misread. I thought there was a `hasY(hasY const&) = default;` but there wasn't. This doesn't compile on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/izWJmQ).

Comment: @RaymondChen: Now I've edited the code (last paragraph): Adding a unique_ptr means this class has no copy control operations thus the program works because it uses move constructor not copy one.

Comment: The book is wrong (as you yourself demonstrated). Having no move constructor is different than having a deleted move constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit move vs copy operations and containment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086366/implicit-move-vs-copy-operations-and-containment)

Comment: If the proposed duplicate does not address all your concerns, perhaps the other issues should be isolated from the question about the book?