# Passing ownership of stack object without duplication

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-memory

A third-party library has the API `Huge computeHuge()`. It returns the object itself, not a reference/pointer. I have no control over the object or the API.

I've got two classes:

```
class Bar {
  Huge h;
  Bar(Huge &huge): h(huge);
}

class Foo {
  Bar b;

  Foo() {
    Huge h = computeHuge();
    b = Bar(h);
  }
```

Unfortunately, this design results (temporarily) in two copies of a huge object: one copy exists in the `Foo` constructor, and another exists inside the `Bar` object. Once the `Foo` constructor exits, there is only one copy, but I need double the memory inside the constructor. Since `h` could be hundreds of GB, this matters.

One solution to this problem is to make `Foo` the owner of `h`:

```
class Bar {
  Huge &h;
  Bar(Huge &huge): h(huge);
}

class Foo {
  Bar b;
  Huge h;

  Foo() {
    h = computeHuge();
    b = Bar(h);
  }
```

This does successfully eliminate having two copies of `h`, but it doesn't really make sense in my application: `Bar`is the Right Thing to hold `h`.
How can I:

1. Call `computeHuge()` in the `Foo` constructor
2. Let `Bar` retain ownership of `h`
3. All *without* ever needing two copies of `h` in memory?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you could have hundreds of GB on the stack. Usually, the default stack size is 1 MB. I think `h` internal data is dynamically allocated (assuming you have a RAM memory big enough to store hundreds of GB, which I seriously doubt). But if you have access to `Huge`'s internal data, you could perhaps hold a pointer to it instead.

Comment: True. `Huge` is a wrapper around a very large vector, and this vector is presumably allocated on the heap. But I don't have any control over it because the `Huge` object in `Foo()` will be cleaned up when the constructor exits, which will delete the vector. Even if I could access the internal vector, I coudln't keep it from being deleted when the constructor exits. I am using a *very* large EC2 instance, so plenty of memory :)

Comment: As advised in the given answer, you can move your `std::vector` (If you can't move `Huge` directly, which would be preferred). It should do the trick :)

Comment: ^ if not that:  Make Bar generate the (empty) Huge object, then have an get-huge-reference function in Bar, then use that to fill out the object in Foo?  Like a get-image-buffer type function in image libraries?

Comment: @DaveS Can you write that up as an answer?

Comment: You must have a default constructor for `Bar` somewhere right? When you create `Foo`, `Bar b` must be constructed. Does this in turn create a dummy `Huge h` that is taking a lot of memory? You can initialize `b` in the initialization list of `Foo`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread a key part of the question so my answer won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Huge` is moveable, this does not make any copies:

```
class Bar {
  Huge h;
  Bar(Huge huge): h(std::move(huge)) {}   // move huge into its final place, h
};

class Foo {
  Bar b;

  Foo() {
    Huge h = computeHuge();
    b = Bar(std::move(h));   // move h into constructor argument
    // h cannot be used here anymore
  }
};
```

For debugging purposes, this is a (tiny) `Huge` which can not be copied, but only moved. Every attempt to copy is a compiler error:

```
struct Huge {
    Huge() = default;
    Huge(Huge&& other) { std::cout << "move "; }
    Huge(const Huge& other) = delete;
    Huge& operator=(Huge&& other) { std::cout << "move= "; return *this; }
    Huge& operator=(const Huge& other) = delete;
};
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting the same behavior as before: double memory usage. Perhaps this means that my object isn't moveable?

Comment: Actually, I'm just reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323093/are-there-any-use-cases-for-a-class-which-is-copyable-but-not-movable), and it turns out a non-moveable type is very rare and in some cases can't even be returned from a function, so `Huge` is probably moveable. Unless it has explicitly been made non-moveable, which would not make sense. I played with non-moveable [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5a615a1b9a21228). I think there is a still a copy being made somewhere else.. because as you can see in the previous link, no copy is made with the code here.

Comment: @crockeea Can you change `Huge`? If yes I would `=delete` the copy-constructor and copy-operator=, then every copy is a compile error.

Comment: Nope, it's in an external lib.

Comment: Ok, then I would make a fake `Huge` (updated answer) to see where the copy is made.

Comment: Found the missing `move`. Thanks!