# error C2660: 'std::pair<a,b>::pair': function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++, queue, ordered-map

I am trying to create a structure and insert that a map as following:

```
    struct Queue_ctx {
      std::mutex qu_mutex;
      std::condition_variable qu_cv;
      std::queue<std::vector<std::byte>> qu;
    };

    std::map<std::string, Queue_ctx> incoming_q_map;
    Queue_ctx qctx;
    std::vector<std::byte> vect(100);
    qctx.qu.push(vect);
    incoming_q_map.emplace("actor", qctx);
```

But I get the following error :

```
error C2660: 'std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>::pair': function does not take 2 arguments
 
message : see declaration of 'std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>::pair'

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const char(&)[6],main::Queue_ctx&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const char (&)[6],main::Queue_ctx &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Tree_node<std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>,std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>>>::void_pointer>>,
            _Ty=std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>,
            _Objty=std::pair<const std::string,main::Queue_ctx>
        ]
```

AFAIU, emplace constructs the element inplace. if that is true then why compiler is trying to create pair to emplace?
I see that the syntax of pair synthesized by the compiler is odd that's why it complains. But why does that happen and what can I do to fix this problem ?

I tried to pass `make_pair()` explicitly but that did not help.

If I comment the `qu_mutex` and `qu_cv` then I am able to do emplace. What does error has to do with these two members? Isn't the case that  default consutructor initializing the members of struct ?
I know copy/assignment/move constructors are deleted by the compiler.

Comment: A `std::mutex` isn't copyable.

Comment: @ChrisMM  Hmm so does  `std::condition_variable` and it perfectly makes sense but then error messages is so misleading.   It probably answers my question. Thanks. 
But I would still be interested to know why does compiler emits such message.

Comment: Something related: [Safe and effective way to put a mutex on a container entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276555/safe-and-effective-way-to-put-a-mutex-on-a-container-entry)

Comment: Somewhere deeper in logs it should say that mutex is not copy-able.

Comment: @MarekR Unfortunately, I could did not find that in the logs emitted by the visual studio.

Comment: Try using `try_emplace` instead of `emplace` should give you a much better error message.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep @MarekR  Indeed it does with `try_emplace`  , 

`Error C2280 'attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: C++ error messages can be quite opaque.  They are getting better — which is little consolation — but the future will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway to fix this problem you need customize copy constructor and assignment operator.
Also mutex suggest some synchronization of `qu` in all scenerios, so all fields should be private (so `struct` should be changed to `class`).

```cpp
class Queue_ctx {
    mutable std::mutex qu_mutex;
    std::condition_variable qu_cv;
    std::queue<std::vector<std::byte>> qu;

public:
    Queue_ctx() = default;
    Queue_ctx(const Queue_ctx& other)
        : Queue_ctx(other, std::scoped_lock{ other.qu_mutex })
    {
    }

    Queue_ctx(const Queue_ctx& other, const std::scoped_lock<std::mutex>&)
        : qu { other.qu }
    {
    }

    Queue_ctx(Queue_ctx&& other)
    : Queue_ctx(std::move(other), std::scoped_lock{ other.qu_mutex })
    {
    }

    Queue_ctx(Queue_ctx&& other, const std::scoped_lock<std::mutex>&)
        : qu { std::move(other.qu) }
    {
    }

    Queue_ctx& operator=(const Queue_ctx& other)
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock{ qu_mutex, other.qu_mutex };
        qu = other.qu;
        return *this;
    }

    Queue_ctx& operator=(Queue_ctx&& other)
    {
        std::scoped_lock lock{ qu_mutex, other.qu_mutex };
        qu = std::move(other.qu);
        return *this;
    }

    void push(const std::vector<std::byte>& v)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{ qu_mutex };
        qu.push(v);
    }

    void push(std::vector<std::byte>&& v)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{ qu_mutex };
        qu.push(std::move(v));
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xn6orTedz

It compiles, but more testing is required. Note some functionality is missing to utilize `qu_cv`.

Comment: Thank you, I accept this answer. 
But the way I solve the problem is  replacing the `std::map` with `std::array`.  The key was not really a `string` but an `enum` so it it possible to  use std::array for my use case.