# error: use of deleted function boost::shared_mutex::shared_mutex

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

This is really weird. First I didn't know that you can delete functions and second, this happens in external library.

The circumstances of the error are that I'm using QtCreator to build project AND boost all together, without any static libs whatsoever.

The compiler used is `gcc`

```
myprogram.h:4:7: error: use of deleted function 'boost::shared_mutex::shared_mutex(const boost::shared_mutex&)'
In file included from ../libs/boost155/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:11:0,
                 from ../libs/boost155/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:11,
                 from ../libs/boost155/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17,
                 from ../libs/boost155/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from ../libs/boost155/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from myprogram.h:2,
                 from myprogram.cpp:1:
```

Comment: And [your code reproducing the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is ...?

Comment: I don't even know which code causes it.

Comment: Then you haven't done enough to isolate and identify the issue yourself. But the origin of the compiler error ("`myprogram.h:2`, `myprogram.cpp:1`") could be a good starting point. If that's not helpful, simply keep throwing out code which doesn't involve the `shared_mutex`, until the error disappears. Then, you'll be much closer to pinpointing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to copy a mutex. That is not possible.

You're triggering that from

```
 from myprogram.h:2,
 from myprogram.cpp:1:
```

So, that's *your code*. Probably, if it is not explicit in your code, you have a `shared_mutex` as a member in a class, and this class is getting copied, somewhere as part of the rest of the code.

E.g.:

```
struct MyClass {
    boost::shared_mutex sm;
};

std::vector<MyClass> v;
// etc.
```

`vector` will copy.move its elements during many operations and this would trigger the mutex copy along the way.

For background:

- [Move constructor for std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557179/move-constructor-for-stdmutex/7557212?s=1|3.6687#7557212)

Comment: Wow, you're good. I had the long initialisation of that class - `MyClass inst = MyClass()`. GCC probably treats this differently than MSVC and raises an error. I can't imagine I'd ever figure this myself.

Comment: Call it experience :) Cheers. By the way: [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (requires accessible copy-assignment operator, even if not used)

Answer (score 0):

> First I didn't know that you can delete functions

C++ 11 allows that:

```
struct noncopyable
{
  noncopyable(const noncopyable&) =delete;
  noncopyable& operator=(const noncopyable&) =delete;
};
```

Another similar feature are functions marked as default (`=default`). Good article on MSDN about deleted and defaulted functions: [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx).

> second, this happens in external library.

You try to copy `shared_mutex` from that library - that is not possible. Think about it - what would "mutex copy" represent?

Probably you have some code, that introduces copying - do you store some objects containing mutexes in `std::` containers?