# what are use cases (if any) to make a class non-moveable?

Tags: c++, boost, move

Consider a classic approach to make a class non copyable:

```
// similar to boost::noncopyable
class noncopyable
{
protected:
    constexpr noncopyable() = default;

    noncopyable(const noncopyable&) = delete;
    noncopyable& operator=(const noncopyable&) = delete;
};

class c: private noncopyable
{ /* ... */ };
```

As declaring any copy operation prevents auto-generation of move operations, this automatically makes all derived classes non moveable (by default) also (so full name of `noncopyable` would be `noncopyable_and_nonmoveable`).

Now let's look for classic noncopyable classes from the standard library, e.g. `unique_ptr`. It's noncopyable but moveable, otherwise its utility would be limited. I suppose same is true for many other cases.

Actually I cannot come up with any example when a class should be made non moveable. My argument is: even if a class is not planned to be moved there's a little chance this would be done by a mistake that can cause a harm.

It's actually two related questions:

1) Why `boost::noncopyable` is non moveable also? This causes issues, consider:

```
struct c: private boost::noncopyable
{
    std::unique_ptr<Something> something;

    c(c&&) = default;
    c& operator=(c&&) = default;
};
```

doesn't work ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kRjPgBcGSZmHauc8)) - move operations cannot be generated because they are not generated for the base class. You need to implement them manually -> list your members -> maintenance -> bugs. Just defaulting move operations in `noncopyable` would solve the problem.

2) What are use cases when moveability is harmful so it should be prevented?

Comment: I've made Singleton's non-moveable. It's arguable though.

Comment: @AndyG: why? what mistakes did you try to prevent?

Comment: There was probably a better way, my memory escapes me a bit. But essentially these were Singletons implemented with with "get_instance()" function, so basically a normal class with a static member and static `get_instance`. Should be impossible to construct/copy in any other way, but to enforce that I deleted the copy/move related functions.

Comment: Some design patterns also encourage that objects, once created, are completely immutable. This means that references to them are always valid. Any "mutator" function simply produces a new object that lives in a pool somewhere. These should also be non-movable.

Comment: This should really have been split into two questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-moveable gives you more control over object identity.

If an object is moveable, the address of it can change:

```
moveonly a;
b = std::move(a);
```

Now, anyone how still has a reference to `a` points to a stale object or (something else entirely).

Other situations where this arises is when you have external logic depending on object identity ("address stability") if you will, like e.g. with pthread mutexes: [Move constructor for std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557179/move-constructor-for-stdmutex)

**Addendum** - The naming convention `scoped_XXXX` is oft used to imply non-moveable types (i.e. types guaranteeing immutable instance identity). Contrast this with e.g. `unique_XXXX` which implies a unique instance, that may be moved around. ***Note*** however, the standard library did not adopt this naming convention in full: Example: `std::lock_guard<>` vs `std::unique_lock<>`. C++17 [amends this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) a bit

Comment: object identity aside, I'd also mention object scope; for example, making std::scoped_guard ( or any scoped_whatever ) movable would be a plain lie ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes rather, indeed, `scoped_XXXX` seems to be library-convention to name classes that promise to have fixed identity/reference stability (contrasting with `unique_XXXX` which can move). Let me think about wording that briefly.

Comment: "Non-moveable gives you more control over object identity."
I suppose "you" is author of the class. What's "control"? What's "object identity"? 
The rest of the answer gives a good example but I'm having hard time to comprehend  the first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Why boost::noncopyable is non moveable also?

Very most likely, historical reasons. `boost::noncopyable` is supposed to work with pre-C++11 compilers. There's actually very little reason to inherit from `boost::noncopyable` when using C++11 and beyond. If it were moveable in C++11, how do we establish the same *move* semantics in C++03 compilers?

> 2) What are use cases when moveability is harmful so it should be prevented?

non-moveablity should apply to kinds of resources that are supposedly given to you be an external system - Such as synchronization primitives, objects that represents stuffs like your computer's ACPI platform, and more.

Comment: I can move a `std::ifstream` just fine IIRC

Comment: @sehe. Of cause we can. But I am [talking about](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f792a012aca2f64) global objects like `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::clog`, `std::cin`. Imagine the horror if someone moved their *resource* away somewhere deep in code. :-).

Comment: What's the horror? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed8aaba1beafd86b

Comment: @sehe... I wouldn't be happy if a library I'm using, somewhere in its code path, replaces the streambuf of `std::cout` and fails to restore it.

Comment: I mean, it's not protecting anything then. I'm not saying anything normatively, just noting that `moved-from` `std::ostream` is basically equivalent

Comment: @sehe.. Ahh! Ok. I understand. I will reword my answer. Thank you :-)

Comment: Ironically, actually moving from `std::cout` has _less_ effect (apparently it just shares the buffer): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48e0f936425853b5

Answer (score 0):

**Why boost::noncopyable is non moveable also?**

From the C++11 standard:

> If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared
>   as defaulted if and only if
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
>
> — X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
>
> — the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.

So, I guess that when you `delete` your copy c'tor and/or copy assignment, you prevent the declaration of a default move constructor.

**What are use cases when moveability is harmful so it should be prevented?**

The first thing that comes to my mind is objects that depend on they location in the memory space, such as `mutex`es.