# Copy-constructor deleted implicitly because default definition ill formatted

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I am at the start of building a berkeley simulation in c++. I keep getting this error and I don't understand it's meaning. I looked it up on the internet and it says there are problems if I got no default constructor. But I have one in all classes. This problem occurs when I add the `channel` variable in `TimeSlave`. Can please someone help?

The error is:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘TimeSlave::TimeSlave(TimeSlave&&)’
  : _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }
```

And there is a note which says that the copy-constructor is deleted implicitly because the default would be ill formatted...
Class TimeSlave:

```
class TimeSlave{
    Clock clock;
    Channel channel;
public:
    TimeSlave(string name, int hours, int minutes, int seconds) : clock{name, hours, minutes, seconds} {}
    void operator()(){
        clock();
    }
    Channel* get_channel(){
        return &channel;
    }
};
```

Class Channel:

```
class Channel{
    Pipe<long> pipe1;
    Pipe<long> pipe2;

public:
    Channel(){}
    Pipe<long>& get_pipe1(){
        return pipe1;
    }

    Pipe<long>& get_pipe2(){
        return pipe2;
    }
};
```

Class Pipe:

```
template <typename T>
class Pipe {
    std::queue<T> backend;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable not_empty;
    bool closed{false};
  public:
    Pipe<T>(){}
    Pipe& operator<<(T value) {
        if(closed) return *this;
        lock_guard<mutex> lg{mtx};
        backend.push(value);
        not_empty.notify_one();
        return *this;
    }

    Pipe& operator>>(T& value) {
        if(closed) return *this;
        unique_lock<mutex> ulck{mtx};
        not_empty.wait(ulck, [this](){ return backend.get_size() == 0; });
        return *this;
    }

    void close() {
        closed = true;
    }

    explicit operator bool() {
        return !closed;
    }
};
```

Comment: Mutexes cannot be copied: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/mutex

Comment: `TimeSlave` contains a `Channel` and a `Channel` contains a `Pipe` and a `Pipe` contains a  `std::mutex` and a `std::mutex` cannot be copied because multiple copies of a mutex would defeat the point of a mutex.

Comment: Oh my god.. thank you!

Comment: In addition, to what has already been said: technically, the error is about move-constructor, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius good point. But a `std::mutex` doesn't have a move constructor either. There's a question on that I read a while back. Lemme go fishing.

Comment: Here we go: [Move constructor for std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557179/move-constructor-for-stdmutex)

Comment: @user4581301 Yep, I know. That's why I said "_but the problem is the same_". :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius My apologies. On re-read I see your point.

Comment: Cheap hack solution: `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> mtx;`. Example:  https://ideone.com/0D7A2E . There has to be a better way around this, but I'm not seeing one.

Comment: I couldn't see it, but apparently Howard Hinnant could, so Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with mutexes in movable types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986208/how-should-i-deal-with-mutexes-in-movable-types-in-c)