# Default move constructor with mutex member

Tags: c++, move

I have a class with deleted copy constructors and I'm trying to put a mutex member in something like this:

```
struct A {
    A(const A &other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = default;
    A& operator=(A &&other) = default;

    std::mutex lock;
};
```

The compiler is complaining that I'm trying to call the deleted copy constructor, which I summarise to be due to the std::mutex type being non-movable. How can I make the mutex member play with the move constructors with minimal fuss? I don't actually want to move the mutex member itself into the newly constructed object, and would actually like each moved object to just construct it's own mutex

Comment: This might be interesting: [SO: Move constructor for std::mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557212/7478597).

Comment: I'm not sure whether a `default` move constructor/assignment is a good idea. Shouldn't the `lock` being responsible to guard something? Shouldn't the move construction/assigment consider that `lock` of the moved object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't actually want to move the mutex member itself into the newly constructed object, and would actually like each moved object to just construct it's own mutex

Then simply define your move constructor to construct a new mutex:

```
struct A {
    A(const A &other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &other) = delete;
    A(A&& other)
        : lock()
    {
    }

    A& operator=(A &&other) = delete;

    std::mutex lock;
};
```

Move assignment will still be a problem and should probably just be deleted. Unless you can answer the question: what happens to the existing mutex member when you're being assigned a new value? Particularly: what if you are assigned a new value while the existing mutex is locked?

Comment: I assume being assigned a new value should simply keep the mutex: I understand the OP's design so that the mutex protects the (other) contents of `A`, so copying/moving new contents into `this` should still `this`'s original mutex.

Comment: @Angew I also think that that's what OP wants. However, I do see this as potentially dangerous. The fact that there is an `std::mutex` member here would seem to indicate that that mutex is supposed to protect some critical sections. It should probably not be possible to just change the value of the existing object while the mutex is currently locked…

Comment: True indeed, that basically invalidates my answer. I will have to add a caveat.

Comment: @Angew please do add that and keep my upvote. I do think the wrapper is a nice solution to achieve exactly what was asked for. It's just that what was asked for is potentially problematic to begin with…

Comment: I added a discussion to my answer, I hope it covers it well enough.

Comment: Yes, the idea was that the mutex protects other members of A, and that ultimately a new assignment should just have a new mutex member. This type will not be moved whilst the mutex is locked, although that isn't currently expressed semantically in code, but locking the mutex in the move constructors as mentioned in other answers sounds appropriate for safety

Comment: @Angew I guess it's fine. Of course, it's always a bit dangerous to acquire one lock while holding another, as that opens up potential for deadlock. Self-assignment, e.g., would seem to be an issue then. Using an `std::recursive_mutex` could help with that. Maybe you still wanna point out that that's something to be aware of with the dual lock approach…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel `std::scoped_lock` (and `std::lock()`) at least prevent deadlock, but self-assignment is a good point; I will mention it.

Comment: @Angew True, so that then assumes that whoever is moving already owns the lock on the object being moved from. That's probably the only way to stay sane here…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel It actually assumes the opposite. `std::scoped_lock` is the RAII equivalent of `std::lock()` which is "lock all these lockables at once, in a deadlock-free way."

Comment: @Angew ah, I was not aware of the deadlock avoidance algorithm in `std::scoped_lock`. That's good to know!

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to providing custom move operations for your class, you could create a generic wrapper:

```
template <class T>
class PerObject
{
  T data;
public:
  PerObject() = default;
  PerObject(const PerObject&) {}
  PerObject& operator= (const PerObject&) { return *this; }
  T& operator* () const { return data; }
  T* operator-> () const { return &data; }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
struct A {
    A(const A &other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = default;
    A& operator=(A &&other) = default;

    PerObject<std::mutex> lock;
};
```

The wrapper's copy (and move) operations are no-ops, so the object containing the wrapper will always contain the one it started with.

---

**Caveat:** However, based on how your class uses the mutex, the above could actually be dangerous. If the mutex is used to protect other data within the class, then it should likely be *locked* while the object is being assigned to, so you will have to provide manual move operations anyway. In such case, the code would likely look something like this:

```
struct A {
    A(A&& other) : lock{}, /* anything else you need to move-construct */
    {
      // Note: it might even be necessary to lock `other.lock` before moving from it, depending on your class's exact semantics and expected use.
    }
    A& operator=(A &&other)
    {
      if (this == &other) return *this;  // Otherwise, double-locking would be possible

      // If you need to lock only this object:
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(lock);
      // Alternatively, if you need to lock both objects:
      std::scoped_lock l(lock, other.lock);

      // Now move data from other to this

      return *this;
    }

    std::mutex lock;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to make your move constructor to create new `mutex` when called.

```
 A(A&& other): lock()
 {
     //... move other things
 }
```

You can also use a `std::unique_ptr()` to the `std::mutex` since it is movable.

```
struct A {
    A(const A &other) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A &other) = delete;
    A(A&& other) = default;
    A& operator=(A &&other) = default;

    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> lock;
};

A::A() : lock(new std::mutex())
```

With this approach you'll not create new mutex each time you move the object which will remove some of the overhead.

Comment: Do note that using the `unique_ptr` will have very different semantics from what the OP wants: "I don't actually want to move the mutex member itself into the newly constructed object, and would actually like each moved object to just construct it's own mutex"

Comment: @Angew then the first option works. I just gave another way.

Comment: Then you should probably at least mention how it differs from the first one (and so also from what the OP wants).