# Why is std::mutex neither copyable nor movable?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, mutex, copy-constructor

Could somebody tell the reasons why `std::mutex` is neither copyable nor movable? 
Somebody told me that it has some relationship to avoid resource waste. Why the copy constructor of `std::mutex` should be marked as deleted? If not, is there any potential problem? Its copy constructor is clearly marked as deleted, but I have not seen such declaration for its movement constructor. So why does *cppreference* say `std::mutex` is not movable?

Comment: Logically, what would it mean to copy a mutex? What's the difference between that and just creating a mutex from scratch?

Comment: @TonyTannous Sorry, maybe I mislead you.I **fully comprehend** why std::mutex should be not movable. But I still have a question. **Its copy constructor is clearly marked as deleted**,  **but I have not seen such a declaration for its movement constructor**. So why does cppreference say std::mutex is not movable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the other answers, basic locks such as Mutexes are the most basic objects in the language design providing atomic operations, `lock` and `unlock` here. These might own an OS implemented handle (`native_handle`) that is a handle for a hardware implemented object, and might even skip the intermediate handle.

Copying such a handle of course, is non-trivial (you can't copy a piece of hardware, and sometimes even a OS handle, trivially). Moving it is potentially worse - move leaves the object in an unspecified state, but by its nature, a mutex is shared across threads. If you gut it on one thread, you would somehow have to inform all other threads - more likely you would just have breaking code. This is a lot of overhead for no potential benefit (I can see).

As to why the move constructor is not explicitly deleted in your reference - no default `move` constructor is created if there is a (non-default) defined `destructor` ([12.8, comment 9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf#section.12.8)), so there is no need to delete it.

Comment: What do you mean by "might even skip the intermediate"? Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John Some OS might allow compiled programs to directly write instructions to the hardware implementing the atomic operation, instead of giving an OS handle. Anymore than that I think would deserve a new question.

Comment: If I understand what you mean correctly, maybe, it is directly implemented by the assembly , so there is no OS handle. Am I right?

Comment: @John yes (machine code really), but you are delving way into the deep implementation details that usually don't matter to anyone not implementing a real-time machine themselves. Whether the OS provides a handle or the hardware is directly accessed, the point is ownership cannot be easily copied or moved in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex), I could only see default `destructor` for `std::mutex`, no user defined `destructor` is declared.  Quote from your answer[emphasis mine]:" no default move constructor is created **if there is a (non-default) defined destructor** (12.8, comment 9), so there is no need to delete it." Could you please explain that in more detail.

Comment: @einpoklum Added to the answer.

Comment: @einpoklum second paragraph - added the part why it wouldn't make sense to have a move constructor in general. In short, synchronization problems with no real added value.

Comment: I don't see why a mutex would be different from anything else that's shared between threads. You just need to make sure you don't move the mutex before everyone knows not to use it.

Comment: @einpoklum with no added benefit. This is speculation now, but I feel the standard writers saw no point in adding a move constructor (which must be done explicitly). I can't see good use cases myself. Especially since you're not supposed to handle mutexes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) has no copy constructor. If you send a copy, each will lock it's own copy and you don't prevent race-condition. Helping programmers not shoot themselves in the foot.

[30.4.1 Mutex requirements](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

> A mutex object facilitates protection against data races and allows
>   safe synchronization of data between execution agents (30.2.5). An
>   execution agent owns a mutex from the time it successfully calls one
>   of the lock functions until it calls unlock.

30.2.5 Requirements for Lockable types [thread.req.lockable]

> An execution agent is an entity such as a thread that may perform work
>   in parallel with other execution agents

If you could move, then ownership requirement is broken. And apparently it's already been asked before [why std::mutex doesn't have a move constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557179/move-constructor-for-stdmutex)

To add and quote draft on @Kabanus answer to why move is not marked deleted

12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]

> 20 If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   assignment operator, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if
>   and only if

- []
- []
- []
- X does not have a user-declared destructor
- []

Comment: Why the copy ctor of `std::mutex` should be marked as deleted? If not, is there any potential problem?

Comment: @John probably to meet the requirements for Lockable.

Comment: What about moving, then?

Comment: @einpoklum `A mutex object facilitates protection against data races and allows safe synchronization of data between
execution agents (30.2.5). An execution agent owns a mutex from the time it successfully calls one of
the lock functions until it calls unlock.` If you could move, then it contradicts the c++11 working draft. Is it not?

Comment: What is an "execution agent"?

Comment: @einpoklum *An execution agent is an entity such as a thread that may perform work in parallel with other execution agents* - 30.4.1.1. Somewhat recursive definition.

Comment: @kabanus  I think you misunderstand me. I fully comprehend why `std::mutex` should be not movable. But I still have a question.  **Its copy constructor is clearly marked as deleted,**  **but I have not seen such a declaration for its movement constructor**.   So why does *cppreference* say `std::mutex` is not movable?

Comment: @John See my answer. Also, the first sentence of your question is what's misleading some of the answerers.

Comment: @kabanus I see. I am not a native speaker. :(. I'd reedit it.

Comment: @kabanus Thank you for your clarification. As per the documentation(en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex), I could only see there is a default destructor for std::mutex, but no user defined destructor is declared. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @John I inspected the MSVC definition for mutex and it shows.

Comment: @TonyTannous I see. As per the documentation(en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/~mutex), there is none. You could check it.

Comment: @TonyTannous: In that case, your quote does not explain why an std::mutex should not be movable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer below, mutex handles cannot be copied at the OS level either. In Windows, you have to create a named mutex and then open a new handle based on that name, for example, intended to be used in a new thread/process and std::mutex never creates named objects. So even if there was a copy constructor, it would be impossible to implement it.

Generally, synchronization objects' semantics are different than some plain other object's, even if they are apparently wrapped in a C++ class

Comment: But what about a move constructor?

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis Quote: "So even if there was a copy constructor, it would be impossible to implement it." Why? Could you please explain that in more detail? Is there any potential problem if a copy ctor is implemented?

Comment: There is no API in Windows to copy the mutex. As for moving, it would be possible but why so? It would only lead to bugs.

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis  Why does not provide it?